I switched back to VS 2022 from VS 2022 preview and the cursor insert/visual has lost it mind
In an editor window, when I double-click on text it will change to --VISUAL-- mode, then if I just single click it goes back to --INSERT-- mode on the bottom window status bar.  Why is this happening and how do I change it back?

this seems to be a question or a feedback or bug report for MSFT.

Regarding cursor insert/visual issues, here are the possible causes and solutions:
1: This is a problem that developers often encounter when using Visual Studio. In Visual Studio 2022, Microsoft has introduced several improvements to address this issue, including a new cursor rendering engine that provides a more stable and responsive cursor experience. In addition, Visual Studio 2022 Preview further enhances the cursor rendering engine, making it more stable and responsive.
2: If you have installed plug-ins related to Vim (such as VsVim), these plug-ins will change the editor mode of Visual Studio to a mode similar to Vim (ie, insert mode and visual mode), please disable or uninstall the plug-in.
3: You can try restoring Visual Studio to its default settings: Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings, then follow the prompts to complete.
4: Switch the cursor mode by pressing the Insert key. If this works, you probably don't need to do anything else.

I don't remember installing VsVim, but it was there.  It seems to be a very brain-dead version of Vim.  It is gone now and I am happy.
